# Xcode stuck on Asset Catalog opening

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

My project has a lot of assets. Opening the assets folder makes Xcode freeze. Even creating a new, empty assets folder freezes Xcode once I open it. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Been dealing with this for a couple of days already.

Last thing I did was:

- check any "Massive/Big" image and remove it from the catalog. I found a 17mb image so I remove it from the physical folder ../YourProject/Assests.xcassets.

I did this after:

- deleting DerivedData,
- resetting XCode's default configs
- cleaning up my project dozen times.
- Also I ran ImageOptim on all the pngs in my project just to make sure there were not any corrupted file.

None of that worked until I removed the big file from the Catalog. Funny enough, after been able to open the Assets folder I restored the "big image" and now is working correctly.